# Converting image file into base 64 taking more time

Tags: android

I am using the below code to convert image file into base 64 but it's taking more time to convert.

```
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file");
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos); 
 byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
 String base64= Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

If any one can help please do that!

Comment: first, say what do you need base64 for... and no, you dont need it to upload your image to some remote server

Answer (score 1):

check the size of the image  you are converting .
now a days image size can be very high . so compressing the image before base64 encode will be better. this may reduce encoding time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        name_of_imagefile.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(name_of_imagefile);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 350, 350, false);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes2);

    String encoded = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+Base64.encodeToString( bytes2 .toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 350, 350, false);

Comment: Main thing , you have me customise lenght, width of image by 350,350

Comment: please [edit] your answer to add explanation _in the question_